# How to get the id of the selected item from a dropdown list?

Tags: reactjs

I can get the selected item's value (name), but the is an id and url fro each item beside the name. How can I get those?

```
<select
class = "form-control"
onChange = {
        this.handleSelect
    } >
    {
        allMemesImg.map(item => ( <
            option key = {
                item.id
            } > {
                item.name
            } <
            /option>
        ))
    } 
 </select>




handleSelect = event => {
    this.setState({
        value: event.target.value,
    });
    alert(event.target.value);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a `value` prop/attribute on the `option` elements? Can you update your question to include a more [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, including the value of your state and/or `allMemesImg`?

Comment: @DrewReese I am getting the allMemesImg from this api: https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **value** at your option.

```
handleSelect =(e)=>{
 if (e.target.value !== '') {    
    this.setState({
     value: e.target.value
   })
}
    


<select onChange={this.handleSelect}>
        {allMemesImg.map((item, index) =>
             <option key={index} value={item.id}>
                 {item.name}
             </option>)}
</select>
```

Comment: I don't know how to thank you !!! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to access a selected `id` then add *that* as the `option` `value` attribute. The options's value can be accessed from the `onChange` event's `target.value`.

```
const handleSelect = e => {
  const {value} = e.target;
  console.log({value})
}

return (
  ...
    <select onChange={handleSelect}>
      {memes.map(meme => (
        <option key={meme.id} value={meme.id}>{meme.name}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  ...
);
```

[image: Edit how-to-get-the-id-of-the-selected-item-from-a-dropdown-list]

[image]